# ¿Cómo asignar archivo de certificado en forma de arreglo de bytes a una variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, certificado

Tengo un archivo en un arreglo de bytes:

```
byte[] archivoCertificado = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(directorio + nombreArchivo);
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para convertir el archivo a su forma original en memoria y asignarlo a una variable?

Cuando estaba en alojado en una ubicación de mi PC lo hacía de esta forma:

```
X509Certificate2  Certificado = new X509Certificate2(Valor_pathCertificado , Valor_PinCertificado);
```

Ahora que está en forma de arreglo de bytes ¡no se como hacerlo!

Comment: Según la documentación de la clase X509Certificate2 este puede recibir un arreglo byte en su constructor. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms148413(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

//Asigno el certificado pasando el array de bytes y la contraseña o pin de esta forma

```
 X509Certificate2 MontCertificat = new X509Certificate2(ConvertirCertificadoEnBytes() , Valor.PinCertificado());
```

con este metodo convierto el certificado en un array de Bytes

```
  private byte[] ConvertirCertificadoEnBytes()
        {
            byte[] certificadoBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Valor.PathCertificado());
            return certificadoBytes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes el contenido del archivo en un arreglo de bytes, invoca al constructor del certificado con ese arreglo. El constructor está sobrecargado para recibir justamente este valor, por ejemplo:

```
byte[] archivoCertificado = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(directorio + nombreArchivo);
X509Certificate2  certificado = new X509Certificate2(archivoCertificado, Valor_PinCertificado);
```